# Dot syntax & synthesize

Tags: objective-c, syntax, getter

I was wondering if synthesize has some sort of support for dot syntax.  My goal here is just to learn more about it - I realize I can achieve the goal by defining the getter myself.  I have been looking for info on this topic without much success so far.

Example of what I want to do:

```
@synthesize name = self.someObject.name;
```

Which, as a getter, would be something along the lines of:

```
-(NSString*)name
{
    return self.someObject.name;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The value after the `=` in `@synthesize` must reference an ivar of the current class. You're free to implement the above getter as you've noted, but `@synthesize` won't do it.